# decoding the first 8K of bytes from a binaryNotation string input

Tags: java, base64

I have an image being passed to me in Base64 notation and I wish to decode the first 8K of bytes so I can detect the mimetype using Apache Tika.

I am using java 6 and I am not wedded to any particular Base64 decoder (though I'm playing with iHarder at present). I don't mind using anything as long as it allows me to select just the first 8K of bytes (rather than the whole image file) that I can then feed into apache tika.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "in BinaryNotation"? Can you give us an example? (BinaryNotation doesn't sound like base64...)

Comment: Apologies I meant Base64 notation

Comment: come to think about it I could probably just try decoding the first 100 characters ?

Comment: Well yes, that seems sensible. That will give you 75 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution I found was to simply convert a substring of the Base64 notation string.